# How can I sort an arraylist without using collections.sort()?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have been looking for a while for a way to sort an arraylist without using collections.sort as my own logic is flawed and I have been having a lot of trouble.

I need to sort it in a way that I can use a method I created that basically does what collections.swap does in order to completely sort an arraylist.

Here is my code:

```
public static void mySort(ArrayList<Double> sort){

    int min = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < sort.size() - 1; i++) {
            min = i;
            mySwap(sort, j ,min);

            for(j = 0; j < sort.size() -1;j++){
                if(j < min ){
                    min = j;
                }
            }
    }
}

public static void mySwap(ArrayList<Double> a, int x, int y){

    double temp = a.get(x);
    a.set(x,a.get(y));
    a.set(y,temp);
}
```

I have been having a lot of trouble of with this. Sorry if it is a question is that harming the community.

Comment: Why is `Collections.sort` not good for you?

Comment: Homework question I have been working on for a while. This is just a part of it. I can't seem to figure it out though.

Comment: @AnubianNoob There is nothing wrong with clarifying - sometimes question askers just don't know about something, and visitors should know that the answers are only relevant under a very specific (artificial) limitation.

Comment: "a way to sort an arraylist without using collections.sort" is pretty clear to me...

Comment: *> "Sorry if it is a question that is harming the community."* Yes, I think this question is either low quality or a duplicate of something somewhere. There are numerous articles on the internet about sorting integers (also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Sequence_sorting)) and not to mention [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13727872/1267663) [past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14911816/1267663) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089042/1267663).

Comment: The swap looks like it works, it changes the content of the two indexed elements. You should use Double instead of double (or make it generic or use Object). Your sort loop looks totally broken for a swap sort. I guess you want to compare the values of j and min not the position?

Comment: This is a typical exercise in CS related courses. He wants you to understand how sorting can be done, and probably to learn about its many different and exotic algorithms.

Comment: @Whymarrh, the wikipedia article is useful. I appreciate that. Those other answers I have looked at and they did not help me for this situation. I am new to programming. I'm sorry

Comment: @AndyReutzel I don't mean to come off as abrasive, I understand that new material can be confusing. With that said, Google is your friend. What you are trying to do (based on your snippet above) is what is known as [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). [Maybe this link will be of use.](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/0e6a78e2163be905daa3/raw/SelectionSort.java)

Comment: @Whymarrh Super useful. Thanks so much, I would never come here unless it was my last resort. I did not do a good job researching I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the following algorithm: find min in the rest of the array, swap it with current element starting with first, reconsider *rest* to be array starting of increased +1 index.

You should update your code like this:

```
public static void swap(List<Integer> sort, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = sort.get(i);
    sort.set(i, sort.get(j));
    sort.set(j, tmp);
}

public static void doSort(List<Integer> sort) {
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i < sort.size(); ++i) {
        //find minimum in the rest of array
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sort.size(); ++j) {
            if (sort.get(j) < sort.get(min)) {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        //do swap
        swap(sort, i, min);
    }
}
```

You have a bug with finding minimum and then swapping items. Please note that the code can be improved in many ways (I tried to maintain your let's say way of coding as possible), such as swapping integer references in `swap()`, doing `BubbleSort` like another answer suggests (same algorithm but simpler implementation), using `O(n * log(n))` complexity algorithm, and so on.