# Don't know how to sort an array list from least to greatest without using Collections.sort

Tags: java, arraylist

So i have to create a timeline and i have to put the events in chronological order. It is an array list and in the list are events. Each event has a month/day/year.

Comment: Did you try to google it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529720/how-can-i-sort-an-arraylist-without-using-collections-sort

Comment: what is the structure of your datas ? Is there something with the dates ? (what is an event ?)

Answer (score 2):

Choose one of the options below:

- Write a loop and compare each item in the list to sort them.
- Search on the web, the implementation of `Collections.sort` and use it for inspiration
- Search algorithms for sorting on Internet and implement one of them
- Read this SO question: [How can I sort an arraylist without using `Collections.sort`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529720/how-can-i-sort-an-arraylist-without-using-collections-sort)