# Quicksort in Java - space is bigger than number

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I just wrote a code which read data from `data.txt`, `quicksort` them and write to `data2.txt`

input format is:

```
145 567 
12 3456 
1345 67
```

I need output in format:

```
12 3456 
145 567 
1345 67
```

But i get:

```
12 3456 
1345 67 
145 567
```

Here is the code:

```
private static ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
if (lo < hi){
    int splitPoint = partition(ar, lo, hi);
    sort(ar, lo, splitPoint);
    sort(ar, splitPoint +1, hi);
}
return ar;
}
private static int partition(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
    String pivot = ar.get(lo);
    lo--;
    hi++;
      while (true){
        lo++;
      while (lo<hi && ar.get(lo).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
        lo++;
        }
        hi--;
      while (hi>lo && ar.get(hi).compareTo(pivot) >= 0){
        hi--;
        }
        if (lo<hi){
        swap(ar, lo, hi);
        }else {
        return hi;
    }
  }
}

private static ArrayList<String> swap(ArrayList<String> ar, int a, int b){
    String temp = ar.get(a);
    ar.set(a, ar.get(b));
    ar.set(b, temp);
return ar;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You're comparing _Strings_, not _numbers_. The string "13" is smaller than "14", "135" is also smaller than "14" etc... I think you get the idea

Comment: You`re right. Is there any option to evade it, or I have to read lines as a numbers ? Thank you

Comment: With correct comparison, your sort algorithm still doesn't work correctly. I don't fully understand what's going on in your `partition` method, but it doesn't look like quicksort to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow with Quicksort Java implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907334/stackoverflow-with-quicksort-java-implementation)