# How can I avoid a stack overflow error with quicksorting algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow, quicksort

//
If, like me, the goal is to use the algorithm in some other code (and not to code the algorithm itself), `Arrays.sort` ([Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))) did the job!
//

I keep getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at language.LanguageDetection.sort(LanguageDetection.java:140)
at language.LanguageDetection.sort(LanguageDetection.java:141)
at language.LanguageDetection.sort(LanguageDetection.java:141)
```

And this line :

```
at language.LanguageDetection.sort(LanguageDetection.java:141)
```

Fills the rest of the console output.

I am a beginner in java and I am trying to implement a quick sort algorithm in order to sort a text file containing all dictionary words, so I can then quickly search through it quickly.

I really don't know if this is the way to go or if there would be a more suitable sorting algorithm for this problem, but here is the code :

```
public static void sort(String[] unsorted, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
 if(endIndex - startIndex <= 0) return; //Ends the recursion when unsorted array is of size 1
 String temp;

 char pivot = unsorted[endIndex].charAt(0);

 int j = startIndex;
 for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
 {
  if(unsorted[i].charAt(0) < pivot)
  {
   temp = unsorted[j];
   unsorted[j] = unsorted[i];
   unsorted[i] = temp;
   j++;
  }
 }
 temp = unsorted[j];
 unsorted[j] = unsorted[endIndex];
 unsorted[endIndex] = temp;

 sort(unsorted, startIndex, j - 1);
 sort(unsorted, j + 1, endIndex);

}
```

I don't want to have all the corrected version of the code, just some answers about, what I am coding wrong and if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare you solution with this one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html and see what you can do.

Comment: Does it always cause stack overflow? - or work if the list is short, e.g. 10 items.

Comment: It does sound like you actually need the list to be sorted for some other purpose and that coding a sort algorithm isn't the end goal? So if DIY isn't the goal, just [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) it.

Comment: @weston No, it does not, I tried with a small file and it worked perfectly, maybe a quick sort algorithm is not the right choice or maybe I am implementing it wrong... I keep researching!

Comment: Well it will be limited by the stack. You can't sort millions of items like this without the blowing the stack. If you don't know what that is, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it

Comment: Did you see this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14911816/360211

Comment: @weston Thank you so much! Doing it myself was not the goal and I realize it is way more advanced stuff than I thought, so Arrays.sort does the job, just tested it and it worked!

Comment: Programming lesson number 1, don't reinvent the wheel (unless you're studying the wheel)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution:

Quicksort partitions the input array into two subarrays, and then sorts the subarrays.  To sort the subarrays, first **recurse to sort the smaller one**, and then **loop to sort the larger one**.

Since each recursive call is <= half the size of its caller, the recursive depth is limited to log(N).